# Is there a way I can edit a .jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

Every time I try to edit Minecraft code in eclipse I always go to a .jar file but I can't edit it why is that?

I tried to click on the lines of code, but it never lets me edit the code. Plus, I tried to type on the code, but it never lets me change it.

Comment: The 'jar' you're referring to is a library that the code uses. Eclipse knows the location of the jar and has probably access to the source code. That source code is either packed into the jar along with `.class` files, or in a separate jar or folder. Because contents of a `.class` file are already compiled, Eclipse could (and would not) let you edit the code (would need to re-compile and pack and eventually mess up things for everybody involved). What you could do is to copy that code into your own code, and use that. This way you can adapt your code and still use functions from the original c

Comment: Download the source code (not only the already compiled classes), and integrate it to your eclipse project. Every step is prone to failure: there might be no source available (easily), and if there is, it might not fit easily. It's somekind of riding a rodeo. It takes many steps that cannot easily seen in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to "modify" it

1. Copy code to `src/main/java` override it

Due to the higher loading priority of classpath compared to jar, you can override some java code in your .jar file.

For Example, if you want to modify `StringUtils` in `commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar`

1.1. copy `StringUtils` code to `src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java` (The package path must be consistent with the one in the jar)

1.2. modify `src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java` as you need

1.3. rebuild or rerun your program, the `StringUtils` will use `src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java` instead of the jar one

2. Decompress, Modify, Repackage, Reimport

If you can get the jar source code, you can change the source code can rebuild a new one;

Else you need to decompress it of using `jar xf xx.jar`, then use `jd-gui` to change code, then use `javac` to compile, and use `jar` to compackage. (You can find the specific steps on Google)